# Replace outstanding values from the mean by NA

Tags: r

I would like to take a mean of each row from my data and find out how far from the mean is each value in the row. If the percentage is higher than 50 this value should be replaced with `NA`.

That's the data:

```
structure(list(Name = structure(c(18L, 19L, 5L, 13L, 14L, 31L
), .Label = c("AMC Javelin", "Cadillac Fleetwood", "Camaro Z28", 
"Chrysler Imperial", "Datsun 710", "Dodge Challenger", "Duster 360", 
"Ferrari Dino", "Fiat 128", "Fiat X1-9", "Ford Pantera L", "Honda Civic", 
"Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", "Lincoln Continental", 
"Lotus Europa", "Maserati Bora", "Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", 
"Merc 230", "Merc 240D", "Merc 280", "Merc 280C", "Merc 450SE", 
"Merc 450SL", "Merc 450SLC", "Pontiac Firebird", "Porsche 914-2", 
"Toyota Corolla", "Toyota Corona", "Valiant", "Volvo 142E"), class = "factor"), 
    mpg_1 = c(125, 133, 143, 141, 134, 238), cyl_1 = c(114, 153, 
    112, 136, 128, 155), disp_1 = c(113, 143, 144, 131, 431, 
    331), hp_1 = c(332, 221, 113, 331, 134, 151)), .Names = c("Name", 
"mpg_1", "cyl_1", "disp_1", "hp_1"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

and that's the desired output:

```
               Name mpg_1 cyl_1 disp_1 hp_1
1         Mazda RX4   125   114    113  NA
2     Mazda RX4 Wag   133   153    143  221
3        Datsun 710   143   112    144  113
4    Hornet 4 Drive   141   136    131  NA
5 Hornet Sportabout   134   128    NA   134
6           Valiant   238   155    331  151
```

There are two conditions as well.

1. The only one outstanding value from the row can be replaced with `NA`. It's hard to believe that using 50% cutoff there will be two values because the mean would change completely but look at the second condition.
2. Would be great if the cutoff percentage would be easy to modify. I make go lower than 50%.

Do you have any idea how to do it in efficient way ? Using a loop it looks doable but maybe there is more efficient way?

Comment: From a statistical perspective this is a very bad idea. However, you can do this easily by writing a function that does this for an input vector and then using `apply`.

Comment: @Shaxi Liver, if you only want to change one value per row and the cutoff threshold can be variable, why not just set the value with the biggest deviation from the mean as `NA`? For what it's worth, I agree with Roland that this is not a good idea from a statistical viewpoint.

Comment: What statistical approach could be used in my specific situation ? Would you recommend any test ? The problem is the number of replicates (4). I "know" that some of the results should be statistically relevant but because of one replicate the p-value is usually above the threshold. First of all I would like to test how the situation looks like when I remove those outliers from the data. If I would see what I "expect" I will try to find a statistical approach. If the results remain unclear I will repeat the whole experiment which is 1 year of work.

Comment: I just wanted to add that I was already looking for some help on different forum to find a proper way to analyze my data. Unfortunately I do not have any support from statistician and my knowledge in this field is limited. I did explain the problem under this link: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250164/what-kind-of-statistical-test-can-be-used-for-my-data

Comment: @ShaxiLiver If you don't want what you describe and you want statistical advice, then go ahead and post it at Cross Validated. However, If you post a question here about programming please be sure that is exactly what you want to do before asking people to put time into answering your question.

Comment: Yes, that was the reason why I made this thread. I needed some help with programming but I got some advices regarding statistic so I took my chance in a comment. Thx!

Comment: You seem to be attempting a form of p-hacking. Your goal should not be a significant p-value. It's nice to get one using the proper statistical analysis with data collected during a properly designed experiment that tests a hypothesis. But you should not polish your data if it doesn't give you a significant p-value. You could try using a test that is robust to extreme values if your data is prone to outliers. But removing data points because you don't like your result is a no-no.

Comment: In particular the procedure you've outlined here will give you a biased result.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do understand now. I will try to attack the problem from the other side. I will try to find some other statistical tests which will fit better to my results. The problem is that I am not sure if I have a big choice if the number of replicate is only 4... and that's more about comparing two groups of samples which should be treated as a group. Unfortunately, some of the members of the group do not behave as the rest... The easiest way is to exclude them..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a statistical point view, as @Roland mentions in comments, this is not advised. But If you absolutely have to do it, then,

```
fun1 <- function(x, n){
  t <- which((x - mean(x))/mean(x) > n)[1]
  x[t] <- NA
  return(x)
}

df1[-1] <- t(apply(df1[-1], 1, fun1, 0.5))

df1
#               Name mpg_1 cyl_1 disp_1 hp_1
#1         Mazda RX4   125   114    113   NA
#2     Mazda RX4 Wag   133   153    143  221
#3        Datsun 710   143   112    144  113
#4    Hornet 4 Drive   141   136    131   NA
#5 Hornet Sportabout   134   128     NA  134
#6           Valiant   238   155     NA  151
```